# Bintray 405 not allowed nginx

Tags: maven, github, android-library, bintray, jcenter

I am trying to share my android-library to jcenter by bintray. I have successfully created maven repository on bintray and uploaded my library to repo. But when I am trying to add licence it showing 405 not allowed nginx page.

Why it's not allowing to add licence. Is there anything missing?

I followed [this](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem automatically solved! When I opened my bintray account after few hours and then tried to add license. It worked without any problem. If any one face this kind of problem please wait for few hours this might will solve your problem.